# How to send username as a Parameter in Microsoft Infopath?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, infopath, infopath2010

Hi i'm designing an infopath form which uses a web service and load some combo boxes, this service needs the username of the user as parameter.

I need the form to load data in formload method

How do i set the username as the default parameter in infopath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InfoPath has a built-in function called [`userName()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/05/26/608092.aspx) you can use to get the currently logged in user.  You can use this function in rules such as Form Load, etc.